# Problem with a finite sum involving HurwitzZeta Function

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I'm trying to reproduce some plots from the analytical expression:

$f(\xi)=\left(\frac{2}{\beta^2}-1\right)+\left(\frac{\theta\,e^{-\beta}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\xi+\sum_{n=1}^{60}\left[\frac{(-\beta)^n}{n!}\xi^{1+n/2}\zeta_H\left(-\frac{n}{2},1+\frac{1}{\xi}\right)\right]$.

I need to plot $f(-4x)$ for several values of $\beta$ and with $\theta=0$ and $\theta=1$. In the attached picture, the left panel is what I have to get (ignore the blue curves), but Mathematica gives me a lot of noise.

[image: Left: correct results. Right: My result.]
My code is:

```
f[β_, ξ_,M_, θ_] := ((2/β^2 -1) + ((θ Exp[-β])/2 - 1/2) ξ + Sum[((-β)^n ξ^(1 + n/2))/n! HurwitzZeta[-(n/2), 1 + 1/ξ], {n, 1, M}]);

Plot[{f[0.5, -4 x, 60, 1], f[0.5, 4 x, 60, 0], 
  f[0.8, -4 x, 60, 1], f[0.8, 4 x, 60, 0], f[1.1, -4 x, 60, 1], 
  f[1.1, 4 x, 60, 0]}, {x, -6, 6}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Green, Red, Red, Black, Black}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 8}]
```

Do you have an idea of what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: For now, try using `WorkingPrecision -> 30` in `Plot[]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[β_, ξ_, M_, θ_] := ((2/β^2 - 1) 
      + ((θ Exp[-β])/2 - 1/2) ξ + 
    Sum[((-β)^n ξ^(1 + n/2))/n! HurwitzZeta[-(n/2), 
       1 + 1/ξ], {n, 1, M}]);
```

To use high precision, make the input parameters exact values.

```
Plot[{
  f[1/2, -4 x, 60, 1],
  f[1/2, 4 x, 60, 0],
  f[4/5, -4 x, 60, 1],
  f[4/5, 4 x, 60, 0],
  f[11/10, -4 x, 60, 1],
  f[11/10, 4 x, 60, 0]},
 {x, -6, 6},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {Green, {Green, Dashed}, Red, {Red, Dashed}, 
   Black, {Black, Dashed}},
 PlotRange -> {0, 8},
 WorkingPrecision -> 50,
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Just change the styles back to get rid of the dashes.

Comment: Thank you all guys. It solved my problem. :)